# How to use tf.gather in batch?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have a `A = 10x1000` tensor and a `B = 10x1000` index tensor. The tensor B has values between 0-999 and it's used to gather values from A (`B[0,:]` gathers from `A[0,:]`, `B[1,:]` from `A[1,:]`, etc...).

However, if I use `tf.gather(A, B)` I get an array of shape `(10, 1000, 1000)` when I'm expecting a `10x1000` tensor back. Any ideas how I could fix this?

**EDIT**

Let's say `A= [[1, 2, 3],[4,5,6]]` and `B = [[0, 1, 1],[2,1,0]]` What I want is to be able to sample A using the corresponding B. This should result in `C = [[1, 2, 2],[6,5,4]]`.

Comment: Are you sure you want `tf.gather` operation? Maybe provide example of `A` and `B` with smaller dimensions and write what exactly do you expect to get as output. The `tf.gather()` works as it supposed to and you won't be able to achieve the shape  `10x1000` with it given your `A` and `B` tensors.

Comment: Ok, I'll try an example. Let's say A= [[1, 2, 3],[4,5,6]] and B = [[0, 1, 1],[2,1,0]]
What I want is to be able to sample A using the corresponding B. This should result in C = [[1, 2, 2],[6,5,4]]

Comment: It could be pretty easily done with gather, but are you going to manually set 1000 indices?

Comment: @Sharky No, the 1000 indice are a flattened volume (10x10x10). I have 10 of those volumes. The first dimension represents the volume (A) and its corresponding indices (B).

Comment: @FelipeMoser, Append the example of input-output that you've provided in comments to your question.

Comment: @FelipeMoser, Were you able to understand my answer?

Comment: @Vlad Yes I did, and it does indeed work. However, unstack doesn't work while training

Comment: @FelipeMoser, I've added the solution for the case where the first dimension (batch size) is unknown in advance. This solution is going to work in every case.

Comment: @Vlad thank you for your help. I just realized that while tf.get_shape doesn't work, Keras.shape does so I went with that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. *Dimensions of tensors are known in advance.*

First we 'unstack' both the parameters and indices (`A` and `B` respectively) along the first dimension. Then we apply `tf.gather()` such that rows of `A` correspond to the rows of `B`. Finally, we stack together the result.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def custom_gather(a, b):
    unstacked_a = tf.unstack(a, axis=0)
    unstacked_b = tf.unstack(b, axis=0)
    gathered = [tf.gather(x, y) for x, y in zip(unstacked_a, unstacked_b)]
    return tf.stack(gathered, axis=0)

a = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]), tf.float32)
b = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([[0, 1, 1], [2, 1, 0]]), dtype=tf.int32)

gathered = custom_gather(a, b)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(gathered))
# [[1. 2. 2.]
#  [6. 5. 4.]]
```

For you initial case with shapes `1000x10` we get:

```py
a = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.normal(size=(10, 1000)), tf.float32)
b = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.randint(low=0, high=999, size=(10, 1000)), dtype=tf.int32)
gathered = custom_gather(a, b)
print(gathered.get_shape().as_list()) # [10, 1000]
```

**Update**

2. *The first dimension is unknown (i.e. `None`)*

The previous solution works only if the first dimension is known in advance. If the dimension is unknown we solve it as follows:

- We stack together two tensors such that the rows of both tensors are stacked together:

```
# A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]        [[[1 2 3]
#                            --->     [0 1 1]]
#                                    [[4 5 6]
# B = [[0, 1, 1], [2, 1, 0]]          [2 1 0]]]
```

- We iterate over the elements of this stacked tensor (which consists of stacked together rows of `A` and `B`) and using `tf.map_fn()` function we apply `tf.gather()`.
- We stack back the elements we get with `tf.stack()`

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def custom_gather_v2(a, b):
    def apply_gather(x):
        return tf.gather(x[0], tf.cast(x[1], tf.int32))
    a = tf.cast(a, dtype=tf.float32)
    b = tf.cast(b, dtype=tf.float32)
    stacked = tf.stack([a, b], axis=1)
    gathered = tf.map_fn(apply_gather, stacked)
    return tf.stack(gathered, axis=0)

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], dtype=np.float32)
b = np.array([[0, 1, 1], [2, 1, 0]], dtype=np.int32)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 3))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(None, 3))

gathered = custom_gather_v2(x, y)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(gathered, feed_dict={x:a, y:b}))
# [[1. 2. 2.]
#  [6. 5. 4.]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `tf.gather` with `batch_dims=-1`:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

rois = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[3, 2, 1]])
ind = np.array([[0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2]])
tf.gather(rois, ind, batch_dims=-1)
# output:
# <tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 10), dtype=int64, numpy=
# array([[1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
#       [3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1]])>
```